# Wordpress,how can I convert textareas to use a wysiwyg editor?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have a question about wordpress. I am creating a web form for branch managers to enter data into a database, one of the fields can contain bullet points so I need to use an editor that will allow the user to use bullets and then convert it to html like the way wordpress handles posts. Is there a way to make text areas use the tinymce editor? I tried using mceTextarea but it didn't do anything. Anyone know how to add editor options to textareas?

Comment: Like this?  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Comment: yes! that works, thanks I don't know how I missed that

Comment: No problem. I found it almost by accident when I was looking for something only tangentially related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Making this an answer so others can find it.)

WordPress has a function called [`wp_editor()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) that creates a WYSIWYG editor anywhere you need one.